# Right way of doing a keyboard click?

Tags: javascript, html, key

In the HTML file I just have a simple thingy that detects the clicks:

```
<body onload="document.body.focus()" onkeyup="return keypressed(event)">
```

In the JavaScript that calls this up, we have:

```
function keypressed(e) { 
    var intKey = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if(intKey==13) {/* If enter is clicked, do something */ return false;}
    // Add as many key detects under here...
    return true;
}
```

Is this a good way of checking after clicks? The reason I ask is just that I have used this quite some time and just wondering if there is a better way.

**For record, the purpuse of this question is to find the best way. And by that I mean with and without jQuery!**

Comment: What do you mean by "checking after clicks"?  Keyboard keys are "pressed"; mouse buttons are "clicked".  What are you trying to catch?

Comment: Are you planning to use any JS lib like JQuery?

Comment: As you see... when a person clicks enter something... something happens. Maybe bad of me to say.

Comment: @Phil No, that is not allowed.

Comment: We do not use jQuery in my county.

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to listen globally on a specific object rather than body for a key press.

In JQuery this would be accomplished as such:

```
$('#el').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        alert('keypressed');
    }
});
```

Comment: Lol I am just filling up the rest of this comment to say that one word :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about cross browser but tested in `Chrome` and `Firefox`, if this helps

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.body.onkeyup=function(e){
       var keyCode = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.which;     
       if(keyCode==13)
       {
           return false;
       }
       else
       {
           //alert(keyCode);
           // do something...
       }
    };
}
```

Comment: agree. without jQuery, I would still take the javascript out of the HTML and place it in a separate javascript file. the less javascript code you intermix into your html, the more maintainable your project becomes.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, which homogenizes key codes and event properties between browsers as well as helps you keep inline code out of your HTML files:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
   $( this ).keypress( function( event ) {
      alert( event.which );
   };
} );
```

Comment: Can I do this without jQuery? :)

Comment: No since you said no to libraries and frameworks, that's why I deleted my answer.

Comment: @user1431627 Yes, it is possible since jQuery is just JavaScript code, but you would basically be reinventing the wheel trying to duplicate what is already done.

Comment: Oh, sorry... I did not mean it like that. The purouse of this question is to find the best way and yeah. I do not like jQuery, but people reading this might be using jQuery and want to make the code in jQuery.

Comment: jQuery can end up making your code a lot less verbose.

Comment: Oh, well I +1 JQuery or another lib since it is, as @dqhendricks said, reinventing the wheel

Comment: My uncle told me about the interview that talked about this. jQuery is like fast food and you do not really know the ingredients, plain JavaScript is home made and you know what is in it.

Comment: @user1431627 Except you can look right at the _javascript source_ for jQuery... Now, I'm not lobbying for jQuery in this case but that's a poor argument.

Comment: Do you grow your own food as well? I know exactly what's in JQuery I have even modified its base code.

Comment: @user1431627 That may have been good advice when jQuery was just starting out, but these days, it is a standard, and can help immensely in speeding up code writing.

Comment: There are other libs out there, some who think like you, barebones, they make you learn JS but they simplify things, take a look on Google there is one to suite almost every type of person now-a-days.

Comment: People, people. Do you like your moms home made food or do you like cheapy fast food? Fast food is easier, but contains trans-fat and make you put on weight. When you make home made food you know what is in it and you don't put on extra weight. Think of the extra kilobytes of code as the trans-fat - it makes your website fatter.

Comment: @user1431627 I would say it is a good idea to learn plain JavaScript before learning jQuery, but once you have a strong command over JavaScript, you should definitely look in to using libraries like jQuery.People who only learn jQuery, and do not understand plain JavaScript will definitely have troubles during interviews and whatnot.

Comment: @user1431627 you still buy your carrots from the super market right? Think JQuery as more like that, you gotta cook it you just buy the ingredients

Comment: @user1431627 those extra kilobytes would have to made by you anyway to cater for the criss cross browser standards out there, JQuery has in recent versions tried to slim itself by only catering for browser fixes and leaving the weight to plugins.

Comment: @user1431627 Compare not using jQuery to still using assembly as your language of choice because you have "more control" over it, even though it takes 100x as long to write anything, and whatever you write will probably not be as high quality as something you write in a more modern language.

Comment: Do you guys hate your elders, people?

Comment: @user1426486 your code actually becomes far more bloated without jQuery. There is something to be said about code readability over avoiding a kilobyte download. Almost every major web application uses open source JavaScript technology like jQuery, and jQuery being the primary one.

Comment: Well then you are doing it the right way, though you prolly got other parts of your site which would be better with a browser standard compliant JS library but that's for another day when you realise coding it yourself is horrid and you start making mistakes and slow points in your code.

Comment: @user1426486 I am starting to think you are just trolling us haha.

Comment: I am not trolling.. Look I just want to use normal plain JavaScript instead of calling a whole frame work just for one thing.

Comment: You are doing it right, I suppose :P; ok enough joking, yea that's the right way to do and best way

Comment: Well said, only for one thing you shouldn't use jQuery!

Comment: So, there is not a better, cooler, nicer, smaller, etc way of doing this. Is that correct, officers?